# How to raise voltage output of charge controller IC due to cable loss?

Tags: lithium-ion, voltage-measurement, charging

I am using a [CN3703](https://datasheet.octopart.com/CN3703-Consonance-datasheet-10742501.pdf) IC to charge a 3 cell li-ion pack (layout as below.)

[image]

The charge current is programmed using a resistor between its CSP and BAT pins which develops a voltage drop of 200mV. The output voltage on the BAT pin is preset to 12.6V (+/-1%.)

Due to cable and connector voltage loss, I want to raise the output voltage so that 12.6V (instead of 12.4V currently in my previous layout) reaches the battery. I am not sure exactly how to do this as there is no mention in the datasheet, but I came up with the following circuit (circled in red.)

The idea is is that 99% of the voltage is fed back to the IC so that it raises its output by 1% to around 12.72V.

- Would this modification likely work?
- How large can I make these resistor values without them introducing significant error?

EXTRA INFO: I should mention that I have already modified (U6) INA219 breakout by swapping the 0.1ohm resistor with a 0.01ohm resistor.

Full Schematic from **working** prototype and picture of PCB 
[image]
[image]
[image: schematic]

UPDATE: Some very helpful comments. I have redone the layout to put the shunt before the battery sense so that the chip sees the voltage of the battery directly. I have also switched to a XT30 connector for the battery so that i am not using the same connector for the input power and the output charging cable. I have also moved the battery connector closer to the IC and used a short wide plane to connect them. Finally I have avoided using vias for the high current path by placing the low current signals on the other side.

[image: Revised Layout]

Comment: Just a comment on updated circuit/photo. **Never** use same connector for power input and output! Change barrel diameter, change gender... in any case do something to prevent accidental wrong connection.

Comment: Thanks I will do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is in those **absolutely unnecessary** voltage dividers R7/R8, R11/R12.
You basically adding 500 Ohm load to the charger's output and also shifting feedback voltages, messing up all the charging profiles the chip is designed to follow.

Remove R8, R12, C10 and put jumpers instead of R7, R11.

Also, what on Earth is R2 doing there? If you want a discharge path (again, absolutely unnecessary) for that tiny 10uF capacitor, put 1M there, not 22k

Finally, **don't use VIAs in high current path**. You have through-hole pad on VIN+. Why would you take a trace on one side only to bring it to the other with VIA if you already have same pad on the other side?

UPDATE:

One more thing. The whole premise of this post is an attempt to tweak output of the charger to accommodate the voltage loss in some (supposedly) too long or too thin charging cable. This is like attaching RV trailer to Fiat 500 and then tweaking the carburetor hoping it will go.

What if you change the cable tomorrow? What if somebody uses different gauge cable?
IMHO, you are fighting self-created problem here.

UPDATE 2:

> is there a way to compensate for the lower than expected output
>   voltage?

There might be, but IMHO it is not worth doing. First, the standard way to detect end of charge of lithium battery is to monitor *current* while in constant voltage stage. If you use correct shunt resistor and use short appropriately sized feedback traces then battery will probably be charged OK.

Second, you should focus on minimizing voltage losses in your wiring. Heavy and as short as possible PCB traces, no VIAs, good connector, heavy and short cable. See if you can find alternative to INA219 with lower than 20uA input bias. Then you might be able to share shunt, further reducing voltage drop.

Also, I'd definitely try another chip or two to see if this lower than expected voltage is a fluke or a norm for this IC.

Regarding discharge resistor - similar ICs from TI and AD with built-in power path technology often use ideal diodes internally, to minimize both forward drop and leakage current. Maybe it worth checking those out. In any case, I would definitely use larger value. Keep in mind that it essentially drains the battery when it left connected with no power applied.

Comment: The working circuit doesn't use the dividers. I am trying to understand if they can help me raise the output voltage of the chip.

The 20k resistor was from the datasheet but i can remove it.

Thanks I will swap the two signals onto the bottom layer and put the high current path on the top so that it doesn't change from top to bottom and back.

Comment: Then post the _actual schematics_ and maybe PCB of working circuit. Who knows what problems you have there? I am looking at [datasheet](https://datasheet.octopart.com/CN3703-Consonance-datasheet-10742501.pdf) and I don't see any resistor there

Comment: Its on Page 10 bullet (2) "To avoid erratic operation, a resistor in parallel with capacitance C1 may be needed to discharge the capacitance, the resistor value is determined by diode D1’s leakage, generally speaking, a 20KΩ resistor can achieve the task."

Comment: @user1247060 those comments describe _built-in_ charger design, when it is permanently attached to the battery and supply is disconnected. You need to adjust the typical application circuit to your specific application.

Comment: My original question is phrased badly and I believe the issue is that the battery IC's reference is set a bit lower than 12.6V. I can measure 12.44V on the BAT pin when in sleep and with the battery disconnected. This tiny difference is close to the limits of the specification of the chip (+/-1%) but far enough such that the cells never reach 4.2V.

Aside from try another chip in the batch i have, or switch to an IC with a tighter tolerance, is there a way to compensate for the lower than expected output voltage?

Answer (score 1):

> The idea is is that 99% of the voltage is fed back to the IC so that
>   it raises its output by 1% to around 12.72V.

And the battery will get charged to 12.72 V. Not a good idea!

> Due to cable and connector voltage loss i want to raise the output
>   voltage so that 12.6v (instead of 12.4v currently in my previous
>   layout) reaches the battery.

Cable and connector losses are resistive, so their voltage drop is proportional to charging current. Once the charger detects peak battery voltage it will wind the current down, so the cable/connector voltage drop reduces and the battery still reaches full charge voltage.

The only bad effect of resistance in the charging path is that the current will start to taper off sooner than it would without the extra resistance, so the charge time will be a bit longer. This the same reason an old battery (with higher internal resistance) takes longer to charge.

Comment: Thanks I should add that the battery pack itself has its own protection which will disconnect the battery if one or more cells reaches 4.25V.

Comment: The protection circuit is only for last-ditch protection against charger malfunction. Relying on it to cut charge off will stress the battery and make it more likely to suffer catastrophic failure. If the battery normally only gets to 12.4V at rest then it will have ~98% of full charge in it, and be stressed less so it should have longer life. Better to give up a tiny bit of capacity rather than try to squeeze in the most charge possible and then have the battery only last a few cycles!

Answer (score 0):

> The charge current is programmed using a resistor between its CSP and BAT pins which develops a voltage drop of 200mV.

By adding this INA219 breakout, you add another 0.1Ω and thus another 200 mV voltage drop. This is the cause of the additional voltage drop.

You should swap the positions of both sense resistors:

- remove the INA219 breakout board and connect R10 directly to connector J2. That way the battery voltage is correctly measured and maintained at 12.6V.
- insert the INA219 breakout board between L1 and R10 (and have CSP and BAT still connected to R10).

Better not to share one 100 mΩ sense resistor for both current sensing ICs because cabling introduces noise/additional resistance.

Comment: I am already using a 0.01ohm resistor on the INA219 breakout

Comment: The  ESL of wires can induce noise if not balanced and shielded or twisted, but if you have cable loss, use a heavier braided cable.